# masterpage meta tags are winning over childpage meta tags

Tags: asp.net, seo, meta-tags

I want to know if there is way to change meta description on specific pages, but to keep the meta data from the master page for the pages where I haven't specified any info. 
I am trying this approach:

```
    HtmlHead headTag = (HtmlHead)this.Header;
    HtmlMeta pageMetaTag = new HtmlMeta();
    pageMetaTag.Name = "Description";
    pageMetaTag.Content = "Test";
    headTag.Controls.Add(pageMetaTag);
```

Which adds the description tag properly, but I want in same time to remove/disable the meta tag from the master page.
Is that possible?
Thanks in advance and have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Meta tags belongs to http headers. In a master-content page design they are usually part of the master page. But this isn’t required! **You can integrate a ContentPlaceHolder into the header section of the master page**. With this approach you can easily set meta tags and other header elements in content pages.

If you need meta tag defaults, you can introduce a design with two nested master pages, where the outer master page contains the ContentPlaceHolder for the header and the inner master page contains the default header.